# Pyinstaller will create an executable with --onefile, but not without it

Tags: python, pyside, pyinstaller

The problem I am having is that when I run pyinstall plotGUI.spec, it creates a working --onefile .exe. The problem with that is I don't want one file, seeing as how I have things writting to files, and the temp directory getting deleted is of no use. So I want to create an exe without the --onefile command, and everything I do isn't working. The new spec file gives me an exe which returns the following error message:

```
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. 
Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more details.
```

I do not know where the application log or how to use sxstrace (I am not usually a windows user, just need it for this project.) I am running WinPython 32bit 2.7.6.4 on Windows 7 64 bit (I need the 32 bit python for a module.)

Here is my spec file that creates the working --onefile exe:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['plotGUI.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner'],
             hiddenimports=['scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx','PySide.QtCore','PySide.QtGui'],
             hookspath=None,
             excludes=['PyQt4'],
             runtime_hooks=None)

a.datas += [('DejaVuLogo.ico', 'C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner\\DejaVuLogo.ico',  'DATA'),('DejaVuLogo.png', 'C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner\\DejaVuLogo.png',  'DATA'),('temp.npy', 'C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner\\temp.npy',  'DATA'),('threshold.npy', 'C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner\\threshold.npy',  'DATA')]

for d in a.datas:
    if 'pyconfig' in d[0]: 
        a.datas.remove(d)
        break

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='DirtScanner.exe',
          debug=True,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True , 
          icon='DejaVuLogo.ico')
```

This is the other spec file that isn't working.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['plotGUI.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner'],
             hiddenimports=['scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx','PySide.QtCore','PySide.QtGui'],
             hookspath=None,
             excludes=['PyQt4'],
             runtime_hooks=None)

a.datas += [('DejaVuLogo.ico', 'C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner\\DejaVuLogo.ico',  'DATA'),('DejaVuLogo.png', 'C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner\\DejaVuLogo.png',  'DATA'),('temp.npy', 'C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner\\temp.npy',  'DATA'),('threshold.npy', 'C:\\Users\\Wesley\\Documents\\DirtScanner\\threshold.npy',  'DATA')]

for d in a.datas:
    if 'pyconfig' in d[0]: 
        a.datas.remove(d)
        break

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='plotGUI.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='plotGUI')
```

EDIT: I found the event log for the program. It seems to be an issue with Microsoft Visual, specifically the debug, but why would it have the issue with one and not the other?

```
Activation context generation failed for      
"C:\Users\Wesley\Documents\DirtScanner\dist\plotGUI\plotGUI.exe.Manifest". 
Dependent Assembly 
Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",
publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",
version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. 
Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```

I have tried reinstalling some visual studio, but so for nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much struggle, I tried using py2exe, which also failed, and then switched to cx_freeze. After getting it to compile with cx_freeze, it spit out an error message, basically telling me which part of my code didn't have the needed dlls. It turns out, for some reason, SeaBorn was causing the error. By commenting it out, the above spec file worked for the code.

Comment: What exactly is SeaBorn? I don't understand your solution. I cannot even find it in the code above?

Comment: My solution lies within the code I was trying to compile. Seaborn is a python library (http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/). I cannot show the actual code, but the above code for compiling worked, once I took out the seaborn library